# Omit index.php from URL on IIS

Tags: url

Is there a way to omit index.php from the URL when using IIS server? Adding

```
'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
```

seems to break the site (except for the front page). index.php is removed from the menu links, but when called the sub-pages result in a 404.

This is my first Craft site on IIS, and I have no experience with IIS. It is the client choice unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running the latest IIS 10 on Windows 10 and "pretty URLs" (i.e. `craft.dev/admin/dashboard` worked out-of-the-box using Craft's stock `web.config` file in the public HTML folder with no modifications.

I'd double check you've got that file in place and haven't made any modifications to it.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Yes, that was the problem. The server owner had disabled the file because with it on the server would throw errors (500 if I recall). It hasn't been fixed so I have just had to go ahead with index.php in each URL.